# Transposing and formatting data on the correct sheet in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, worksheet-function

I want to copy data given to me (finite column range, but dynamic rows), and paste it transposed into a second sheet within Excel.

From there, I need to convert all the values in columns D, E, F, and H to fractions out of 12. I'm pretty sure I'm almost there, but the last step (converting to fraction text) is being performed in the wrong worksheet.

I tried the `.Activate` function as well as setting the correct worksheet.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub FormatData()

Dim ws As Worksheet

' create a new worksheet, and name it "Master"
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add(after:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1))
ws.Name = "Master"

' copy the UsedRange and Transpose
Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Copy
ws.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll, Transpose:=True

Sheets("Master").Activate

Dim i As Long, N As Long, j As Long
N = Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
j = 2
For i = 2 To N
    Cells(i, "D") = WorksheetFunction.Text(Cells(i, "D"), "0 0/12")
    j = j + 1
Next i

j = 2
For i = 2 To N
    Cells(i, "E") = WorksheetFunction.Text(Cells(i, "E"), "0 0/12")
    j = j + 1
Next i

j = 2
For i = 2 To N
    Cells(i, "F") = WorksheetFunction.Text(Cells(i, "F"), "0 0/12")
    j = j + 1
Next i

j = 2
For i = 2 To N
    Cells(i, "H") = WorksheetFunction.Text(Cells(i, "H"), "0 0/12")
    j = j + 1
Next i
    
End Sub
```

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10714251/9758194) is a must read for you to help you overcome this issue

Answer (score 0):

first only do only one loop and do all four conversions inside that one loop. Second, j is not doing anything, you can omit it.

```
Sub FormatData()

    Dim ws As Worksheet

    ' create a new worksheet, and name it "Master"
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add(after:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1))


    With ws
        .Name = "Master"

        ' copy the UsedRange and Transpose
        Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Copy
        .Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll, Transpose:=True

        Dim i As Long, N As Long
        N = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row

        For i = 2 To N
            .Cells(i, "D") = Application.WorksheetFunction.Text(.Cells(i, "D"), "# ??/12")
            .Cells(i, "E") = Application.WorksheetFunction.Text(.Cells(i, "E"), "# ??/12")
            .Cells(i, "F") = Application.WorksheetFunction.Text(.Cells(i, "F"), "# ??/12")
            .Cells(i, "H") = Application.WorksheetFunction.Text(.Cells(i, "H"), "# ??/12")
        Next i
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! For some reason though excel is outputting all the fractions correctly when I test it, except 10/12. It's converting .83333 to 5/6. Any idea why this might be happening?